# Get in java a float number sent from Arduino as uint8

Tags: java, arduino, xbee, uint8t

I'm making an app which sends float values from arduino (using an Xbee to transmit) to an application in Java (using an Xbee to receive).
The problem is that when I receive the data in Java I'm not able to convert it to the original float number I've stored in the xbee packet.

That's what I've,

Arduino:

```
uint8_t* data;
float value = (voltage*100)/5;
data = (uint8_t*)(&value);
for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(data); i++) Serial.println(data[i]):
Serial.println(*((float*)(data)));
```

Here I take the float value and I store it in data array as bytes. For example, for value 22.66 what i get in the first print are the values 0 and 72 (data size is 2 after store the float value). The second print gets 22.66. So it seems that the value is stored correctly.

After that I send the data to Java in a Xbee packet and I get the data like this in Java:

```
XBeeResponse response = xbee.getResponse(2000);
int[] data = response.getProcessedPacketBytes();
System.out.println(data[7] + " " + data[8]); //these positions contain the values stored in arduino -> data[7] = 0 and data[8] = 72)
```

I'd like to know how to get the value 22.66 in java from the positions data[7] and data[8].
I've tried some things like:

```
int value = (data[7]) | (data[8]<<8);
float valuef = Float.intBitsToFloat(value);
```

But it didn't work.

Anyone have any idea about how I could do that?

Thank you!

PS: if it helps, i'm using the following xbee libraries in java and arduino:
https://github.com/andrewrapp/xbee-api
https://github.com/andrewrapp/xbee-arduino

Comment: You should be using `sizeof(value)` which will be 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need ir yet:

In Arduino:

```
    #include "XBee.h"

    #define SensorAPin (2)
    #define SensorBPin (3)

    float fSensorA ;
    float fSensorB ;
    XBee xbee = XBee();

    uint8_t payload[8] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    union u_tag {
        uint8_t b[4];
        float fval;
    } u;


    // SH + SL Address of receiving XBee
    XBeeAddress64 addr64 = XBeeAddress64(0x0013a200, 0x40a300ee); 
    ZBTxRequest zbTx = ZBTxRequest(addr64, payload, sizeof(payload));
    ZBTxStatusResponse txStatus = ZBTxStatusResponse();

    void setup() { 

    Serial.begin(9600); 
    xbee.setSerial(Serial);

    }

    void loop() { 
    if (!isnan(fSensorA) && !isnan(fSensorB)) {

        u.fval = fSensorA;
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
          payload[i]=u.b[i];
        }
        u.fval = fSensorB;
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
          payload[i+4]=u.b[i];
        }

        xbee.send(zbTx);
      }
    }
```

In Java:

```
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.ByteOrder;

    import com.digi.xbee.api.listeners.IDataReceiveListener;
    import com.digi.xbee.api.models.XBeeMessage;
    import com.digi.xbee.api.utils.HexUtils;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class MyDataReceiveListener implements IDataReceiveListener {
        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see         com.digi.xbee.api.listeners.IDataReceiveListener#dataReceived(com.digi.xbee.api.models.XBeeMessage)
         */
        @Override
        public void dataReceived(XBeeMessage xbeeMessage) {
            System.out.format("From %s >> %s | %s%n", xbeeMessage.getDevice().get64BitAddress(), 
            HexUtils.prettyHexString(HexUtils.byteArrayToHexString(xbeeMessage.getData())), 
            new String(xbeeMessage.getData()));

            byte[] bytes = xbeeMessage.getData();
            byte[] byte_var1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes,0,4); 
            byte[] byte_var2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes,4,8); 
            float f_sensor1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(byte_var1).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).getFloat();
            float f_sensor2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(byte_var2).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).getFloat();
            System.out.println("variable 1: "+ f_var1);
            System.out.println("variable 2: "+ f_var2);


        }

    }
```

Comment: In arduino you are sending an uint_8 byte[] array, so in Java you have to read that byte array and decoding to IBM floating point format, so to separe the bytes that represent each one float sended from arduino, you can use Arrays.copyOfRange() to create a sub-bytes array of each float, then you can use the bytebuffer function to get the float of each one sub-byte array: ByteBuffer.wrap(byte_var1).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).getFloat();

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
float myFloat=ByteBuffer.wrap(yourByteArray).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getFloat();
```

use order ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN,ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN or ByteOrder.nativeOrder() according to your float to uint_8 conversion method.